# Learning English pronunciation

Tags: windows, language

I want to improve my English pronunciation.

Is there any program that could ask me to read some words or sentences aloud, record my pronunciation and then allow me to listen to my voice?

- The program should be able to compare my voice recording with a standard English accent (American or British).
- I would prefer if it runs on Windows.
- I don't mind about the price.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Auralog](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auralog)'s [Tell Me More](http://store.tellmemore.com/):

- Windows
- record your voice and can compare it with a standard English accent (American or British):

[image]

[More details for the latest version](http://store.tellmemore.com/English-Lessons-and-Exercises-on-Software-CD-DVD-p/v10.5_english_dvd-rom.htm).

Comment: This software is not available anymore, it was bought by Rosetta Stone.

Answer (score 2):

Saundz (http://saundz.com/) is mainly focused on the speech process itself, i.e. demonstrating how particular sounds or words are created, which is represented by the virtual animation. The software teaches 40 basic American English sounds and over 400 words that you can listen to and record. You can compare your voice with sample recordings of native English speakers - after you send your recording, it's played back next to a native speaker's so you can hear the difference.

There's a Windows desktop application, but it also works in browsers. Here's a screenshot:

[image: Saundz]

Answer (score 1):

[Rosetta](http://www.rosettastone.eu/) [Stone](http://www.rosettastone.com/us_assets/documentation/RSV3_UG_CD_English_(US).pdf) can evaluate speech using graphs.
The graphs on the speech analysis screen help you evaluate and improve your speech patterns by giving you a visual comparison of your speech with native speaker's speech.
Today the company offers courses in 24 languages English included and it runs on Windows: XP SP3, Vista SP2, Windows 7, or Windows 8 or Mac (Intel based only): Snow Leopard, Lion, Mountain Lion (OS X 10.6 or higher).

Answer (score 0):

One could use the Microsoft's OpenAI Service for Pronunciation Assessment for Language Learning. Details from some email I received from them on 2023-07-23:

> We would like to share the great news that we have recently released Pronunciation Assessment for Language Learning in new languages and new features. With this update, Pronunciation Assessment is publicly available in 20 languages and variances including American English, British English, Australian English, Chinese, French, German, Italian, Japanese, Korean and Spanish.This feature supports comprehensive language learning solution such as chat bot for learners and educators worldwide, enabling learners to receive detailed feedback on their pronunciation skills and identify areas where they need improvement. At recent 2023 Microsoft Reimagine Education event, we announced several great new features to support student success. Pronunciation assessment is used in Reading Coach on Immersive Reader and the Speaker Progress in Teams. It can be used inside and outside of the classroom to save teachers time and improve learning outcomes for students on reading fluency. Pronunciation assessment is also used in PowerPoint coach to advise presenters on the correct pronunciation of spoken words throughout their rehearsal. In English, you can now try out mispronunciation feedback in a more natural way while practicing the pronunciation including more familiar phoneme name in IPA format, more readable granularity score on syllable level, as well as the recognized phoneme expression user actually speaks as a clear comparison to the targeted phonemes. As technology continues to advance among the services available such as Speech to Text, Text to Speech, Custom neural voice (CNV), Conversation Transcription Service, Speaker Recognition, Speech Translation, Speech SDK, and Speech Device Development Kit (DDK), it's becoming increasingly clear that the future of education lies in the integration of AI. Azure AI is at the forefront of this revolution, providing education companies with powerful tools to improve the learning experience and drive student engagement and achievement.
>
> Get started today:
>
> - Check out [Azure blog about language learning](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/3-microsoft-azure-ai-product-features-that-accelerate-language-learning/https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/3-microsoft-azure-ai-product-features-that-accelerate-language-learning/) for more details.
> - Explore the [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/ai-services/speech-service/how-to-pronunciation-assessment?pivots=programming-language-csharp) to test Pronunciation Assessment for Language Learning today.
> - See [sample code](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk/blob/5b2aa44055b529ec3bd7c961efbe6a151f93ee5e/samples/csharp/sharedcontent/console/speech_recognition_samples.cs#L970) and [full language support and region list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/ai-services/speech-service/language-support?tabs=pronunciation-assessment).