# English pronunciation software for a learner

Tags: windows-7, educational, language, speech-synthesis

I am trying to improve my English pronunciation and I would like to know about the best solution / software available, which accepts English words / sentences as text input, and thus I can listen to their pronunciations.

In my Windows 8.1, there is an app called **[Advance English Dictionary (AED)](http://apps.microsoft.com/windows/en-in/app/advanced-english-dictionary/3206ef20-ac28-4001-926b-005a4b5dad2e)**, which has an option for the users to listen to both UK and US english pronunciations. Below is a screenshot:

[image: Advance English Dictionary]

I am happy with this one, but unfortunately, it won't work in my Windows 7 PC. So is there any better and quality alternate solution, compatible with Windows 7, other than its built-in text-to-speech facility? I am looking for the one which supports UK accent.

Comment: Related: [Learning English pronunciation](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/4172/903)

Comment: The website http://www.thefreedictionary.com/ provides pronunciations of all English words.  It cannot do the same for sentences.